# How to log into Chegg with Python?

Tags: python, authentication, python-requests

I have a free trial of Chegg and would like to save the solutions to a few chapters for my math textbook.

What I would like to do is open the link for each solution, and save that webpage as a PDF using Python 3. I was able to figure out the code to save the site as a PDF using some libraries including Requests. However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to log in.

I watched (too) many videos and read tutorials, but I can't figure out what my payload should include when sending a request to Chegg. I've easily been able to log in to some other sites, but Chegg doesn't have typical stuff that others do, such as "username" and "password" fields in the code (when you look at the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools). Does anyone know what I'm missing? How can I can send a request to log in to Chegg specifically, without using any "complex" things like Selenium (I'm a beginner)?

Comment: Why don't you copy authenticated cookies from your browser?

Comment: @t.m.adam Hmm, so I can send cookies in my request, and this will allow me to not sign in? I'm not quite sure how to structure this request...

Comment: Either copy the cookies as a string and pass it in the headers parameter, `.get(url, headers={'Cookie':cookies})` or create a dictionary and pass it in the cookies parameter, `.get(url, cookies=cookies)`. Web sites keep track of users with cookies, so if your request has authenticeded cookies it should have the same privileges as your user account. Of course, you could try to reproduce the login process with requests, but I think the method I proposed is easier.

Comment: "...Chegg doesn't have typical stuff that others do, such as "username" and "password" fields in the code (when you look at the Network tab in Chrome Developer Tools)" - are you sure? I looked at the Network tab while signing in, and it clearly sends a POST to `https://auth.chegg.com/auth/_ajax/auth/v1/login?clientId=CHGG` with both email and password. Please check it once.

Comment: @t.m.adam The cookies thing worked. Thanks so much! If you'd like to write it as an answer, I'll upvote and mark it as the best answer :)

Comment: Glad to be of help, but I won't post an answer, sorry. If you think my suggestions could benefit other readers, you can post answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> Why don't you copy authenticated cookies from your browser?
> – t.m.adamOct 20 '19 at 10:09

> Either copy the cookies as a string and pass it in the headers
> parameter, `.get(url, headers={'Cookie':cookies})` or create a
> dictionary and pass it in the cookies parameter, `.get(url, cookies=cookies)`. Web sites keep track of users with cookies, so if
> your request has authenticeded cookies it should have the same
> privileges as your user account. Of course, you could try to reproduce
> the login process with requests, but I think the method I proposed is
> easier.
> – t.m.adam Oct 21 '19 at 0:27

Thought I would post this so that people that find this question won't miss the answer in the comments!